# How to create a log of each function which was called while my server was running? for debugging purposes

Tags: debugging, server, node-debugger

How can I create a log of each function that was called while my server was running, for debugging purposes?

I am trying to understand and debug the source code of a node library (specifically y-websocket).
I am running the library locally. After closing my server I want to get a log of each function that was called, in the order they were called.
Thank you!

I have tried using node --inspect, but the node debugger requires me to set breakpoints.